# Usage of „zur Warnung“ versus „als Warnung“

Tags: phrase

To signify „as a warning” , both the terms “zur Warnung” and “als Warnung” seem to appear quite frequently:

> [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Warnglocke):  Glocke, die **zur Warnung** geläutet wird

> [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=als%20Warnung&corpus=kern&h=1&from=): Jerusalems Konzept der Roten Linie wurde im Oktober 1975
> entwickelt - **als Warnung** an Damaskus vor einem zu massiven
> Eingreifen im Libanon.

Is my assumption that both mean “as a warning” correct and what are the differences in usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, both mean "as a warning".
I think both terms are used in slightly different contexts:

- zur Warnung
  It's often used for something that is used to inform people about a possible threat (a bell, a sign...)
- als Warnung
  Something is done to threaten someone or is used as a deterrent. You do something
  to demonstrate of what you are capable of.

However, I think it's usually still not totally wrong to use the respective other one in the context. These are only nuances.

Comment: The distinction between an established signal ("zur Warnung") and a threatening act ("als Warnung") may be blurry - is the head of a dead horse in your bed the former or the latter?